# importError:cannot import name 'home_page' from 'shop.views'

Tags: python, django

I am a newcomer and I wrote Hello Word to start practicing and I use Django==3.1
and python3 and I encountered this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'home_page' from 'shop.views'`

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import home_page

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('',home_page),
]
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the file directory structure of the project? If you use Django projects in VSCode, you could refer to this document: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django

Answer (score 1):

You should add your `app_label` to the import as well. `from {app_name}.views import home_page`

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for you

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include
from . import views
```

`path('', Home.as_view(), name='home'),`

You may also consider, `path('', views.home),`

Answer (score 0):

** urls.py:-**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from {app_name}.views import home_page

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('',home_page,name='....'),
]
```

In 3rd line you need to add your app name inside `{app_name}`....